dynamically applied transitions using react-transition-group not appearing
So i am building a react app that contains a slice component, each slice contains 2 project components. when i hover over one project i would like to minimise the one that isnt being focused on and maximise the one that is. but i cant seem to envoke a smooth transition using react transition group. right now nothing happens at all when i hover but the components do re render.
here is my CSS
.minimized-enter{
    opacity: 0;
}
.minimized-enter-active{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.minimized-exit{
    opacity: 1;
}
.minimized-exit-active{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.maximized-enter{
    opacity: 1;
}
.maximized-enter-active{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.maximized-exit{
    opacity: 0;
}
.maximized-exit-active{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}

here is my Slice.js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Project from "./Project";
import "./Slice.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

export default function Slice(props) {
    const data = props.sliceData.projects;
    const [projectElements, setProjectElements] = useState([]);
    const projectUIDs = [uuidv4(), uuidv4()];
    const [animationClassStrings, setAnimationClassStrings] = useState(["", ""]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const elements = [
            document.getElementById(projectUIDs[0]),
            document.getElementById(projectUIDs[1]),
        ];
        setProjectElements(elements);
    }, []);

    const handleMouseOver = (index) => {
        if (animationClassStrings[index] === "maximized" || animationClassStrings[index] === "maximized") return;
        let tempAnimationClassStrings = [...animationClassStrings];
        tempAnimationClassStrings[index] = "maximized";
        tempAnimationClassStrings[index ^ 1] = "minimized";
        setAnimationClassStrings(tempAnimationClassStrings);
    };

    const handleMouseOut = (index) => {
        if (animationClassStrings[index] === "" || animationClassStrings[index] === "") return;
        let tempAnimationClassStrings = [...animationClassStrings];
        tempAnimationClassStrings[index] = "";
        tempAnimationClassStrings[index ^ 1] = "";
        setAnimationClassStrings(tempAnimationClassStrings);
    };

    const generateProjects = () => {
        return data.map((project, index) => (
            <Project
                key={uuidv4()}
                uid={projectUIDs[index]}
                projectData={project}
                animationClassString={animationClassStrings[index]}
                onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseOver(index)}
                onMouseLeave={() => handleMouseOut(index)}
            />
        ));
    };

    return <div className="slice">{generateProjects()}</div>;
}

here is my Project.js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import "./Slice.css";

export default function Project(props) {
    // declare state variables
    let [mainImage, setMainImage] = useState(null); // mainImage is the first image to be displayed in the project
    // declare utilities
    let data = props.projectData; // data is the projectData object passed in from Slice.js
    let elementAry = [
        <img src={mainImage} alt={data.name} />,
        <h1>{data.title}</h1>,
    ];
    const contentOrientation = data.orientation === "image--left" ? 0 : 1;

    import(
        process.env.PUBLIC_URL +
            "/public/assets/ProjectImages/" +
            data.mainImage
    )
        .then((image) => {
            setMainImage(image.default);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error importing image: ", error);
        });

    let generateContent = () => {
        return (
            <div
                id={props.uid}
                className={"projectWrapper"}
                style={{ backgroundColor: data.color }}
                key={uuidv4()}
                onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter}
                onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}
            >
                {elementAry[contentOrientation]}
                {elementAry[contentOrientation ^ 1]}
            </div>
        );
    };

    return (
        <CSSTransition in={true} timeout={500} unmountOnExit classNames={props.animationClassString}>
            {generateContent()}
        </CSSTransition>
    );
}

any help is appreciated
ive tried changing the transition to see if my styles are the issue but that didnt change anything. i would like one to fade out while the other one fades in.
